# How to use ng-mouseover for hide and show input element on mouse hover

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code:-

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="name" required />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" >
               <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here I am using bootstrap class `input-group` which contains two elements i.e `<input>` and `<span>`
So here I want to show that button on mouse hover.
So I tried by using `ng-mouseover`

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-mouseover="open" >
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
     </button>
</span>
```

Where open is :-

```
$scope.open = true;
```

I think `ng-mouseover` is better option but if is there any other simple way....  please tell me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.open = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div ng-mouseover="open = true" ng-mouseleave="open = false">
    To display button mouseover here!!!
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-show="open">
      <i class="fa fa-plus">Button</i>
    </button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

try this. also you can use `:hover` for show/hide element.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-show="open" ng-mouseover="open = true" >
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: ok it's working but when I leave mouse then I want it to be disappear